# Aws dynamodb how to represent all the jobs for a user

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

My app runs jobs for a user.  I store the result files in S3.  But I store the job object (configuration and run status) in dynamo db.

I use a UUID as the job id and primary key.  However, I need to list all the jobs for a user.  Each job knows the username who created it.

What is the best way to list the jobs for a user?

There are several ways I considered:

1. Store the list on a user object.
2. Make username the primary key and id the sort key.
3. Store an entry in S3 before it runs and list objects with the username prefix.
4. Create a secondary index on username

Storing a redundant list seems problematic because I have to keep it in sync when storing a job.

Since sort key is really for different versions of the primary key. It feels wrong, because most of what I am doing is getting a job using it's id.

I can store an S3 entry before the job runs. But it feels like a kludge to store an empty result.

I guess the secondary index makes the most sense but it seems expensive just to gather a list.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a use-case to read the items stored in DynamoDB using the job-id? If you don't, then I would use user-id as PK and job-id as SK.

However, if you also need to get jobs by their id, then id use a Global Secondary Index for user information. To save on costs, use projection type `KEYS_ONLY`, this will only store the user-id and job-id on the GSI.